# How to pass variable from adapter to bottomSheetDialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to use intent in order to pass the list "todo" from TodoAdapter to NewTaskSheet which is a file for bottomSheetDialog but I have no idea how to get it correctly. The idea is that I need to get a list of Todo objects in NewTaskSheet and add these new objects by clicking on the Save button. Then recycler view should print added objects on the screen. It is the logic of my todo app.

TodoAdapter

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster


import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.TextView


import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ItemTodoBinding



class TodoAdapter(
    val todos: MutableList<Todo>
):RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder( ItemTodoBinding: ItemTodoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val ItemTodoBinding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        return TodoViewHolder(
            return TodoViewHolder(ItemTodoBinding)
        )


    }



    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked:Boolean){
        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val curTodo = todos[position]

          holder.itemView.apply{
              val tvTodoTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle) as TextView

              tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title

              val cbDone = findViewById(R.id.cbDone) as CheckBox
              cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
              toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
              cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                  toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                  curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked


              }

              cbDone.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{

                      todos.removeAll{todo->
                          todo.isChecked
                      }

                      notifyDataSetChanged()



              })


        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
          return todos.size
    }



}
```

Todo

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster

data class Todo(
    var title:String,
    var description:String,
    var isChecked:Boolean=false
)
```

NewTaskSheet

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster

import android.os.Bundle

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView

import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment




class NewTaskSheet() : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding
    private lateinit var todo: Todo




    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentNewTaskSheetBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view:View,savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            todo = Todo(title="",description="",isChecked = false)
           binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener {
              todo.title=binding.title.text.toString()
              binding.title.setText("")
               binding.description.setText("")


           }


    }




}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle



import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.bignerdranch.android.taskmaster.databinding.ActivityMainBinding



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter:TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)




        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())
        binding.rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
        binding.rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener{
            NewTaskSheet().show(supportFragmentManager,"NewTaskTag")
            }


    }

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTodoItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTodoDone"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTodoDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Done"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_todo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_new_task_sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".NewTaskSheet">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Task"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="100dp" >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:hint="Title"/>




    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="170dp" >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:hint="Description"/>




    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="250dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments in your `clickListener` as following:

```
val bottomsheet = NewTaskSheet().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(key to value)
        }.show(supportFragmentManager,"NewTaskTag")
```

to send it to your bottomsheet and then retrieve the data as following:

```
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
      String myValue = this.getArguments().getString(key)
       ...
      }
```

Maybe you might need to serialize/[parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) the list in order to put it in a bundle.

I would also suggest to save the bottomsheet instance in a nullable variable and dismiss and clean it up `onDestroy` to avoid memory leaks